# POST a form using cURL to a cross-domain url and add form data to local database

Tags: php, forms, post, curl

After much searching of resources I've not been able to quite achieve what I've been after.

I have a form (index.html) that, on submission, is being added to a database (submit.php). After that, two fields (name and email) are being submitted to a url that is not on the same domain - our clients CRM deals with it.

This works fine, except that the page that is returned at the end of the request is still submit.php and the content is the response from the other url instead of redirecting the header to the location that I have set.

This is what handles the cURLing.

```
$url = 'https://another.url';

    $fields = array(
        'name-field' => $name,
        'email_address' => $email
    );

    $post_string = http_build_query($fields);
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 2);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_string);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);

    if ($result){
        header('Location: success.html');
    }
```

Any ideas on how I can achieve the redirect after the cURL request?

Thanks all for your support.

Comment: try using this : curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

Comment: also, before closing curl, check `curl_errno($ch)`, more info [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-errno.php).

Comment: On first impressions this seems to have worked! The form has submitted ok with a good response and the page redirected to my success page. I'm just waiting confirmation from the guys that own the CRM that the submission is there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$url = "https://another.url?email_address".$email;
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
$result = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

if ($result){
    header('Location: success.html');
}
```

Comment: This reads more like a game of spot-the-difference than an answer. What did you change? Why should it fix the problem?

Comment: I can see that you've added in the returntransfer and verifypeer. Return transfer I've now used as per Ranjith's comment and seems to work. Is ssl verify peer now necessary if it works?

Comment: It is good if you can verify SSL, but in many cases it fails, than you need to disable that option.

Comment: if Ranjith's comment ans work then doesn't need to change

Comment: I would like to tick Ranjith for the answer, but this will do in it's virtually the same. Kudos to skobaljic for recommending the curl_errno

Comment: glad to here my comment help you:)

Comment: Yep - Just had confirmation that everything has gone through correctly on their end too. Thanks a lot.